# WCF calling another WCF: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have two WCF hosted on two different HTTPS websites with different certificates. WCF(a) calls WCF(b) and vice-versa with an if clause to cancel the possible infinite loop.

Every time the method of both WCF is called, it returns the error:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS
```

I tried installing the certificates in the Trusted Root Certificates but the error still appears. Avoiding the WCF-calling-another-WCF is not an option, unfortunately.

Any fix for this?

UPDATE:

I've tried hosting both in the same website and it worked so I'm thinking this is specific to the certificate being used? So should the same certificate must be used? or is there a possible way to use different websites with different certificates?

Comment: Is the failure in both directions or, say, only and a calls b? Do the certs match the DNS names? Are the certs valid in terms of expiration, etc? Is the revocation list accessible?

Comment: at the moment both are using self-signed certificates. so yes, it fails whichever WCF is used. I've updated the post too.

Comment: Can you show the service configs - are you using message or transport security? What binding(s) are you using?

Comment: the app is silverlight so i'm using basichttpbinding with transport security

Answer (score 3):

When you use self signed certificates you need to have the certificate validation return true in your client that access the WCF service.

The code is as shown below:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         return true;
                                                                                     };
```

Just place this code before you invoke your service method.

Also Since you have 2 services A and B calling each other the above code should be in both places when you make a call. The above is to trust the certificate as its not from a trusted certificate provider.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. But for the SO users that might stumble on this, this code is only applicable for development and testing and not for the actual release of the application, right?

Comment: Yes. Since you are using self signed certificates the above code applies. Is it that you are using client authentication using certificates as well

Comment: You must *NEVER* ship such code in production. You are opening yourself up for man-in-the-middle attacks, which will be trivial to pull off.

Comment: How does that change things? Certificate validation should never be disabled in production. You could change the validation logic, but it should never be just "return true;" or you will be attackable.

Comment: Even if this worked for me, I can't mark this as the answer because it defeats the purpose of the certificates. I'm looking for a secure way for the WCF to call the other WCF. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: @Nasko: You are not disabling any validation logic in production. Since the service A acts as client to service B you specify that the certificate is to be trusted in the call from Service A to Service B and once the call is over you set the callback to null.

Comment: @Bahamut: The above is only valid when using self signed certificates. Once you get proper certificates in place you would not need the above code and you would not have any security issues then. Also you need to make sure to have the certificates in the proper store for it to work

Answer (score 1):

Using self signed certificates for SSL you need to be aware of the following:

1. The certificate needs to be installed in both LocalHost\My and LocalHost\CA stores.
2. The common name part in the subject needs to match the fully qualified domain name for the server. For self signed certificates you can use the public ip address.
3. The account that your service runs under must have read access to the private key of the certificate.

These steps can be satisfied by hosting the services under IIS, and use IIS to generate the server certificate.

Also be aware that wcf usually requires that an CRL is attached to the certificate. But this can also be generated with certmgr.exe.